# Heatsink Question

Tags: pcb, heatsink

Ok so I have designed a circuit and drawn up its PCB and I have a slight question about the heatsink I'm going to use.
Now you'll see in the images below the place where I generally want to place my heatsink. (The yellowish green area.)
My questions are:
A) Is it okay to utilize a monolithic heatsink to service multiple parts (provided you use proper electrical isolation.)
[image]

B) You will see in the second photo a highlighted area a trace falling under where the heatsink will be placed. Will this be a problem (Again assume I will be using some sort of electrical isolation.)
[image]

I already have done calculations based off of thermal resistance to to test my idea I'm just not 100% if it will work. The last image is an example of my basic modeling. I am basing it off of Dave Jones' thermal resistance tutorial videos. I know he only ever did it for one part to a heatsink, but since he said the system could be modeled like an electrical circuit (Replacing current for Power and Voltage for temps) I figured this would work. The node where every thing meets is the Sil-pad or thermal compound touching all of the components before it hits the heatsink.

[image]

Comment: Regarding B, are you intending to place the heatsink in direct contact with the PCB? If not, e.g. it is raised by the height of the components, then the tracks on the PCB will be separated from the heatsink.

Comment: The results will only be as good as your unproven or missing assumptions. Like contact pressure, PTH height above ground plane and compression of 3M and or/SIl-Pad electrical insulator. But the use of a common sink is valid. Missing is the mechanical details. I assume your calculations are valid but the 'C/mW per via thermal resistance you can trust for a given choice of Cu weight , plating thickness, flooded vias or empty, and heatsink contact pressure., moving air or restricted makes a big difference. I don't see clamp holes or design specs for max temp rise like Tja= 20'C to 40'C

Comment: What's with the wonky photo pixelation on round vias looking like a star (Bragg effect?)  Instead of voltage, you can work directly in degrees 'C using the same resistor network in R=Δ'C/W instead of Ω. Moving air over fins reduces R to about 20% at 1m/s unless it is just a flat metal interface to a larger sink, then thermal velocity matters where Al is faster than steel or Cu